# Laravel Architecture - Event vs. Controller

Tags: laravel, events, architecture

My question is related more about the architecture of an Laravel application. I'm developing an application and I have some problems about the positioning of my codes. Let's assume I have a controller to control the comments of my post, but now, after a while, I need to add an action each time a comment is registered, in this case, I create an event or simply add this new action to my controller action?

Thank you.

Comment: You should go with [Model Events](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent#events).

Comment: Ok, that will work! I have some difficulty understanding laravel events... Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Bogdan's says, you should read [Model Events](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent#events).

A sample approach could be the next.
Create a service provider:

```
php artisan make:provider CommentServiceProvider
```

Then a sample CommentServiceProvider class:

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use App\Comment;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class CommentServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        Comment::creating(function ($comment) {
            //... do stuff here
        });
    }

    /**
     * Register the service provider.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }
}
```